# How to vertically align text in each option of a select box?

Tags: html, css, select

I have a select defined with Bootstrap.

```
<select size="12" class="custom-select border border-dark border-2 mb-2"></select>
```

How to vertically align text in each option?

See on picture, on the selected line, "Bergeron, Mégan" is on the top of the area. I want this text vertically aligned.

[image]

Comment: you are using *custom select* plugin?

Comment: I was trying to make something nice following this advices : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/#custom-select

Comment: Please post jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce this on jsfiddle at the moment.